# Delete a record and all the record that precede it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a primary key based on GUIDs. I need to find a record in this table based on the primary key and then delete this record and all the record that appear before it. Is there a command to delete preceding records or can anyone give me some example SQL on how I could do this.

I am using SLQ server 2008

Comment: What do you mean by preceding?

Comment: Records in a table do not have an order (or more specifically, they have an order, but it may not be the order you assume.)  You must be able via the query to explicitly identify what you believe the "previous record" to be.  If you assume all the rows in the table are completely random, how would you query to find the "preceding" row?

Comment: The table also has a date field which I may be able to use to order the records. If so, is it possible to find a give record and delete it and the records that came before it (based on the date field). The first record I need to find must be based on the GUID primary key though.

Comment: A changed my answer to take into account a possible Date Value.

Comment: Could I use a cursor and step through each record deleting them until I find my target record.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, a CURSOR **can be very slow**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you state "*that appear before it*."  or "*preceding records*"  This concept needs to be defined more explicitly. SQL is based on Set theory - and in a set there is no implicit order to the items in the set (rows in the table) You have to define what *preceding* means based on the value of some attribute of the row...

Answer (score 2):

Given the nature of a *GUID* and the fact that you are using it as a Primary Key, then **NO**, you can not accomplish this.

If you have a secondary field that might help with the ordering then *Yes*, or if you had an *IDENTITY* field.

- [Uniqueidentifier vs. IDENTITY](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/uniqueidentifier-vs-identity)
- [The Cost of GUIDs as Primary
  Keys](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862)

**Based on the DateColumn specified:**

Have a look at this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID uniqueidentifier,
        DateVal DateTime
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT NEWID(), '06 Jan 2009'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT NEWID(), '05 Jan 2009'
DECLARE @GUID uniqueidentifier
SELECT @GUID = NEWID()
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT @GUID, '04 Jan 2009'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT NEWID(), '03 Jan 2009'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT NEWID(), '02 Jan 2009'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT NEWID(), '01 Jan 2009'

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table

DELETE FROM @Table
WHERE   DateVal <= (SELECT DateVal FROM @Table WHERE ID = @GUID)

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a GUID as the primary key there cannot be any order determined from it alone (unless you used NEWSEQUENTIALID(), and even that would only be sequential on the same box until restarted), so you need another column, such as a timestamp or Identity to order your rows.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to extract the date/time from *some* GUIDs, depending on how they were created, however it's generally a bad idea. As others have mentioned you should be using an identity or a timestamp -- it's easier, safer and saner.

Relevant links:

- An extraction utility: http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen?typeReq=-1
- Some more technical reading material: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt